# How do I shorten this query DSL for Spring Data repository method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a query to search on different fields based on its present and as a single term. How do I shorten this?

```
Page<DomainSetting>
    findByDomainContainingIgnoreCaseOrGeoContainingIgnoreCaseOrChannelContainingIgnoreCaseOrSettlementContainingIgnoreCaseOrPaymentGroupContainingIgnoreCaseOrDeliveryCountriesContainingIgnoreCase(Pageable pageable, String domain, String geo, String channel,
                                                                                                                                                                                                    String settlement, String paymentGroup,
                                                                                                                                                                                                    String deliveryCountries
    );
```

Comment: You can't shorten this.

Comment: maybe using the @Query is a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$regex` operator is useful in your method with the option `i` to mention that the case is insensitive

Could you try the following method:

```
@Query("'$or': ['domain' : {$regex : ?1, $options: 'i'}, 'geo' : {$regex : ?2, $options: 'i'}, 'channel' : {$regex : ?3, $options: 'i'}, 'settlement' : {$regex : ?4, $options: 'i'}, 'paymentGroup' : {$regex : ?5, $options: 'i'}, , 'deliveryCountries' : {$regex : ?6, $options: 'i'}]")
Page<DomainSetting> findByDomainSettings(Pageable pageable, String domain, String geo, String channel, String settlement, String paymentGroup, String deliveryCountries)
```